# Predicate for filtering by specific managed object - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, tableview, predicate

I have one to many relationship in my core data model ('Client'<-->>Assessment') and in my assessment tableview I am currently filtering assessments by client name.

```
func assessmentFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Assessment")

        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "nsDateOfAssessment", ascending: false)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "client.name == %@", self.client.name)

        return fetchRequest
    }
```

I would like to know how, or if its possible, to filter by the specific managed object instead of an attribute of the managed object ('name' in this case). I've tried changing my predicate to this:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "client.objectID == %@", self.client.objectID)
```

but I just get a crash with an uncaught exception.

I'm wanting to change this because it seems bad practice to filter by name since two clients may have the same name and therefore the same filter results.

Comment: What's the exception that's happening?

Comment: its not giving much info. I set a breakpoint and it sticks where I perform the fetch 'fetchedResultsController.performFetch(nil)'.

Answer (score 0):

So I am going to guess that for you sort descriptor the key name of 'nsDateOfAssessment' is not the actual name of the core data attribute. The key should be the actual name of attribute. Also, I wouldn't say that filtering by first name is bad practice. Perhaps add an additional param to your predicate that can help pinpoint the correct items. Of course, if you are storing a unique identifier for each entity, it would be a cleaner way to go about it.